# Relation between G-connection and second fundamental form when embedding is in principal G-bundle

Tags: riemannian-geometry, connections, principal-bundles

I'm pretty familiar with intrinsic geometry utilized in say General relativity for instance, and I understand the intrinsic curvature $\Omega$ 2-form of a connection $A$ on a manifold $M$ of dimension d.

$$\Omega=dA+A\wedge A$$

When trying to learn extrinsic geometry however, I find myself wanting. Consider some manifold isometrically $M$ embedded within another manifold $N$. Via the Gauss-Codazzi equation we get something like:

$$\Omega'=\Omega+\Pi\wedge\Pi$$

Where $\Pi$ is the second fundamental form. We can write the curvature on $M$ as:

$$\Omega=\Omega'-\Pi\wedge\Pi$$

I would like to better understand the meaning of the second fundamental form from the intrinsic point of view (yes, I know that sounds weird). Suppose the embedding I choose is within $M$'s own frame bundle (let's choose oriented orthonormal) $$M\subset F_{o}(M)$$. For some local trivialization, we have that $$F_{o}(M)=M\times SO(n)$$.

In the intrinsic case, we have curvature in terms of $A\subset SO(n)$, which would seem to be related to the second fundamental form for this choice of embedding.

What is the second fundamental form's relation to a G-connection when the embedding we choose is that principal G-bundle?

Comment: Do you already understand the meaning of the second fundamental form for a submanifold of Euclidean space? And how the abstract formulas in your question translate into formulas using a frame or local coordinates?

Comment: @Deane kind of that point of my question that I'm trying to learn this. I think of it as a measure of how a length as measured on the submanifold changes as you "tug" the submanifold along a normal vector.

Comment: @Deane I get that the local trivialization comes with a set of (ordered orthonormal here) basis which will generally have a non vanishing Lie bracket. As for my question, I think the double tangent bundle comes into play here, which I believe is always trivial for this case (Riemannian manifolds)

Comment: @Deane Honestly I was hoping to use some of the more recent spinor representations of embedded manifolds to describe a connected sum of two manifolds, but the same submanifold will have two normal bundles with some identifying isomorphism (the spinor field?) Where they're glued together on their respective boundaries (the submanifold we've embedded). Does that make sense?